# Textareafor change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm looking for a way to get the input of a Html.TextAreaFor but I can't find a solution.

I Tried out several options, the first one is a change function which only works after exiting and the second one includes a keypress event with two disadvantages: First it fires before text is typed in, second if someone would paste some input it would not work.

Do you have any idea how I can get the exact input after changing the text of an `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text, 10, 50, null)`?

This is the current attempt:

```
$('#Text').on('keyup paste input', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

with:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text, 10, 50, null)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>
```

I also tried to define an id but still no reaction

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a timer, and test when the value changes. Like below:

```
(function($){
   $(document).ready(function(){

   var value = $('#Text').val();

   setInterval
   (
      function()
      {
         if($('#Text').val() == value)
         {
           //do something
         }
         else
         {
            var newValue = $('#Text').val();
            value = newValue;
         }
     },

     1000
   )
 })
})(jQuery);
```

The downside to this is that the `timeout`will run every second for the duration of the page. So make sure to find a way to clear the timeout when you have got what you need.

Comment: Where do I have to paste it? "this" means that it is in another function?

Comment: I have updated my answer to take that into account. So you could just paste it anywhere.

Comment: This function seems only work once, at the beginning but it is not working after the first time.

Comment: Make the `setTimeout` a `setInterval` instead. I have updated the code accordingly.